# cocos2d-x: why are there gaps in my 3d model?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos3d

[image]

see right arm and right leg.

we really workout a perfect model, but after we add animation the gaps appear again. does anybody know why? we use coco2d-x for ios and android.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when the bone data was a bit off. Make sure the parenting of your bones and positioning of your bones always stay the same (distance from each other. Like moving an arm doesn't cause the hand to go further away from the elbow bone). I saw this same problem when the individual bones moved a bit too far away from each other in certain frames.

There's no quick fix for it, I just made sure that every for frame there is no gap in the model. Correct parenting usually fixed this. I hope this helps.

Comment: my gap appears in middle of a bone, not joint, is it same as yours?

Comment: Yes, mine appeared in the middle of a bone, but the joint determines the position. So I moved the "Bone origin" / Joint to close the gap. The joint determines the position, the bone is just an extension to make rotations and precise movement easier. But the Joint determines the position and distance from other parts.